# What does -Dauto means

Tags: java, selenium

I saw the fallowing command for starting Selenium:

```
java -Xmx256m -Dauto=1 -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -log /home/test/selenium.log -trustAllSSLCertificates
```

I googled to find what `-Dauto=1` means but failed.

Comment: You need to example the source of selenium to work out what the `auto` property does, if the documentation doesn't tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `auto` is no valid parameter in a current version of Selenium server. It might have been in the past or it was just used by some custom implementation.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -h
```

will list you all available parameters for Selenium, which you can set by adding

```
-D<variable>=<value>
```

to your start command.

Answer (score 0):

-D is an important switch that allows you to set environment properties.

-Dproperty=value

Set a system property value. If value is a string that contains spaces, you must enclose the string in double quotes:

```
java -D<propertyName>=<propertyValue>
```

You can call the following from anywhere in the code to read it.

```
String value = System.getProperty("propertyName");

 or

String value = System.getProperty("propertyName", "defaultValue");
```